# Or operator with ng-model expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input placeholder="{{a}} || zero">
```

I want to set the placeholder to become 'zero' if the {{a}} is null but that isn't work, it displayed || zero instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The right way:**

```
<input placeholder="{{ a || 'zero' }}">
```

The first step is: Angular calculates the result of the expression inside `{{ }}` - `a || 'zero'`

The second step is: Angular puts the result to the placeholder

**In your variant:**

The first step is: Angular calculates the result of the expression inside `{{ }}` - `a`

The second step is: Angular puts the result to the placeholder

The third step is: HTML appends `|| zero` as string to the placeholder